# Connecting to server with SSH using public key

Tags: debian, ssh, key-authentication

(I've previously [asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1282750/connecting-to-a-ssh-server-using-public-key) on SuperUser, but having tested that the key works fine on a MacBook running OSX, I feel the problem must be with Debian):

#### The problem

I've recently setup a Debian machine (and I don't have much experience with Debian), but I can't seem to properly connect to a server (192.168.1.31) using SSH.

After initial configuration it seems the server accepts my key, but the signature verification fails.

The initial configuration is how I always do it:

1. Generate key (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "my@email.com"`)
2. Add it with `ssh-add`
3. Register public key at SSH server

#### Debian client `ssh dn@192.168.1.31 -vvv`

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/daniel/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.1.31" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.31 [192.168.1.31] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 7.15 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 7.15
debug1: no match: 7.15 FlowSsh: Bitvise SSH Server (WinSSHD) 7.15
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.31:22 as 'dn'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.31
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,ext-info-s
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,3des-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp384 SHA256:kNkp4TIDsSbswddevanXAPgmtwXotVY4aojuRxZmOag
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.1.31
debug1: Host '192.168.1.31' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/daniel/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55cab80f3c40), agent
debug2: key: dn@ordrestyring.dk (0x55cab80f7e90), agent
debug2: key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ecdsa-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:RZPLPu6tVldvSOMjzGq+57kt60onH4zTtiYmpQrWw9Y
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:RZPLPu6tVldvSOMjzGq+57kt60onH4zTtiYmpQrWw9Y
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type
```

#### Server response

```
Authentication attempt from 192.168.2.1:38794 with user name 'dn' suceeded partially. The public key supplied has been verified; requesting signature.
Authentication attempt from 192.168.2.1:38794 with user name 'dn' failed. Signature verification failed
Authentication attempt from 192.168.2.1:38794 with user name 'dn' suceeded partially. The public key supplied has been verified; requesting signature.
Authentication attempt from 192.168.2.1:38794 with user name 'dn' failed. Signature verification failed
```

Comment: Run the `ssh` command with `-vvv` switch to get more verbose log.

Comment: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/publickey-userauth.auto.html

Comment: as per the log, the public key method is discarded, and the  gssapi-with-mic method is attempted

Comment: @RalphRönnquist that is the point of debug log -- it will say why the pubkey method is rejected. But without the debug log, it is hard to guess.

Comment: @Jakuje I have updated it to include the `-vvv` log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is important from the client point of view is the following part of the log:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/daniel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:RZPLPu6tVldvSOMjzGq+57kt60onH4zTtiYmpQrWw9Y
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:RZPLPu6tVldvSOMjzGq+57kt60onH4zTtiYmpQrWw9Y
debug3: send packet: type 50
```

The first line offers the actual public key, the sixth line receives packet 60,  which means [SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh2.h#L119) (corresponds to the first debug line on server). Then we are sending the actual signature using `rsa-sha2-512` PK algorithm, but it is rejected (the answer packet is stripped from your log). This represents the second line on the server -- signature verification failed.

The SHA2 extension is buggy in OpenSSH. I already reported a [bug #2799](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2799), which affects the communication with ssh-agent, in case you are using something different than OpenSSH one. It is directly related to your issue.

From what I see you are using something else (gnome-keyring? What is the output of `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`?) and the server is not accepting wrong signatures provided by this agent. I already filled a [bug for gnome-keyring](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=790910) to resolve this issue in there, but it will take some time to get into GNOME releases.

So for now, the best luck for you is to use ssh-agent or no agent at all. The following command should take you to your server:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK='' ssh dn@192.168.1.31
```

You can also patch your gnome-keyring or build it from master (some additional work). You should be able to use ECDSA keys too, but they are not yet in released gnome-keyring either.

Comment: `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` returns `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`. It seems your suggestion to prepend `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=''` allows me to connect! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yes, it is a `gnome-keyring`. So you are actually hitting this problem, that I tried to describe the OpenSSH developers, but with different server implementation than OpenSSH, which does it "right".

Comment: Apparently, I have the same problem connecting from Ubuntu bionic to an OrangePi running an armbian with Debian stretch userland. I actually get `debug3: receive packet: type 51` when I `ssh` with `-vvv` verbosity, which is likely the error indication you're referring to. ED25519 keys appear to work, though.